# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "autolike para no desaparecer"?

Tags: significado, neologismos, jerga-internet

Cuando leo los comentarios en vídeos de YouTube, frecuentemente veo uno que dice algo como "autolike para no desaparecer." Por ejemplo:

[image]

La explicación más obvia es que los comentarios de YouTube desaparecen si no tienen al menos un *like*. Pero después de pensar en esto, creo que esta explicación no tiene sentido, puesto que en varios videos he visto montones de comentarios viejos sin *like*. Tambien he visto esta frase en otros sitios, tales como Instagram, Facebook, Twitter, y varios sitios menos conocidos. Ningunos de estos sitios borran o borraban los comentarios o las publicaciones sin *like*. Está claro que se trata de una frase con significado no literal o de un meme, no de una creencia genuina sobre el funcionamiento de estos sitios.

Tampoco es el significado obvio. ¿Significa la palabra *autolike* la accion de dar un *like* a su propio comentario, o dar un *like* automaticamente? ¿Es literal, o significa que solamente las publicaciones con al menos un *like* se ve, o que solamente las personas que reciben *likes* tienen visibilidad social?

Creo que esta frase tiene su origen en el español, porque casi no he visto el equivalente en inglés, que sería "autolike to not disappear" o algo así. Los resultados de las busquedas en inglés tienen que ver con programas robóticos que pueden dar los *likes*, por ejemplo.

¿De dónde proviene esta frase y qué significa?  ¿Es algún tipo de meme? ¿Viene de otro foro?

Comment: Obie, la pregunta se ha cerrado porque en realidad no tiene nada que ver con el idioma español, sino con el funcionamiento de un sitio concreto de Internet. Que la gente exprese en español su preocupación sobre la desaparición de los comentarios no hace que la pregunta sea sobre el español. Te recomiendo que preguntes en algún foro especializado en YouTube, o que directamente le preguntes a alguien que hayas visto que ha escrito dicho comentario, para saber por qué lo ha escrito.

Comment: @Charlie - No creo que hayas entendido la pregunta. Intente dejarlo muy claro que de hecho esto no tiene nada que ver con el funcionamiento de YouTube, pero parece que no lo he expresado correctamente. Los comentarios *no* desaparecen en YouTube y creo que el sitio nunca funciono asi. Me pregunto si podria ser algun tipo de meme, creo que esto debe ser asi, porque de otra forma no tiene sentido.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97046/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-charlie).

Comment: Voté por reabrir la pregunta, pero Obie, te pido que incluyas una imagen (screenshot) en la pregunta.

Comment: Ahora que esta pregunta llegó automáticamente a la primera plana, voté por cerrar como *unclear what you're asking* porque el autor no ha vuelto para aclarar con una imagen.

Comment: @aparente001 - Pero sí añadí una imagen. Incluso regresé al sitio de inmediato para arreglarla aunque me había resuelto a no usar el sitio para evitar la obsesión y las discusiones interminables. ;)

Comment: Y sigo viendo videos en YouTube y sigo observando esta frase, que seguramente es propia del español del Internet, así como "tener pelos en la lengua" o "buscarle tres patos al gato" son propias del idioma coloquial.

Comment: I suspect that you have installed an app that works similarly to a chain letter.  I suspect that your facebook account is automatically "liking" a certain number of posts per day, and those accounts are reciprocating and liking yours too, but automatically.  I looked for a youtube tutorial about "autoliker" and found one from India.  I didn't understand the language but I watched as the viewer gets walked through the installation and use of the app, and that is my best guess.

Comment: @aparente001 - When you say "you," do you mean literally *me*? I didn't do anything like that. If you just mean people in general, the use of this phrase goes significantly beyond Facebook. The example is from YouTube, for instance. And I do not think that this refers to a like bot. Why would people be calling out their use of a like bot in their comments?

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Yes.  It's a conjecture.  I could be completely wrong.  I am allergic to facebook and normally stay as far away from it as possible.  However, I watched one video to see if I could figure out where that phrase was coming from.  I did not go so far as to visit the app creator's website.  If the hunch turns out to be helpful for you, great; if not -- unfortunately I can't help any further with this mystery, because facebook is not my thing.

Comment: @aparente001 - Thanks for looking. I have also seen those like bots; however, for various reasons, I think that they are unlikely to be the origin. For instance, the oldest uses I could find seem older than the popularity of the like bots, and I don't think people would want to draw attention to their own botting.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Then where the heck is that phrase coming from?  Not everyone's facebook displays that message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99858/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-aparente001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que significa la accion de dar un like a su propio comentario para que este no pase despercibido por la gente. No tiene nada que ver con la supuesta desaparicion literal de los comentarios, ni con dar los likes automaticamente. Sin embargo, el origen no está claro.

En [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0nAnQzdKs0) reciente (aviso para los que no quieran escuchar groserias) el YouTuber parece creer que la palabra autolike se refiere a la accion de dar un like a su propio comentario y que se hace para ganar la atencion, basicamente como un metodo de autopromocion.

Pude encontrar algunos comentarios que dijeron esto mas abiertamente. Por ejemplo, debajo de [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7zevPed3Ss), hay un comentario que dice:

> Autolike para no desaparecer en este universo de comentarios.

Obviamente este corresponde a la tercera posibilidad que mencione en la pregunta, que sin like un comentario va a desvanecerse entre todos los otros. Por supuesto, el hecho de que una persona use esta frase asi no indica que esto sea el significado original o correcto: puede ser que simplemente interpretara los comentarios que habia visto de esta manera.

No pude determinar el origen de esta frase, pero he encontrado una posibilidad. Si en lugar de buscar "autolike para no desaparecer" busco ["para no desaparecer"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS808US808&ei=g_FeXdGwHY6WsQX9yqQY&q=colabore%20vela%20puerca&oq=colabore%20vela%20puerca&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l4.12780.16987..17198...2.1..0.161.2031.14j7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0j35i39i19j0i203j0i10i203j0i10j0i22i10i30.Qi6YJbQfGiQ&ved=0ahUKEwiR_tHFn5fkAhUOS6wKHX0lCQMQ4dUDCAo&uact=5), veo que hay una cancion que se llama [Colabore](https://www.cmtv.com.ar/discos_letras/letra.php?bnid=167&banda=La_Vela_Puerca&DS_DS=3175&tmid=38086&tema=COLABORE). Salio en el año 2007, antes de las fechas de todos los usos de "autolike para no desaparecer" que he encontrado.

> Colabore para no desaparecer,
>
> Colabore para no desaparecer.
>
> Colabore
>
> Para no desaparecer,  colabore, colabore.

Obviamente en este caso "para no desaparecer" quiere decir lo mismo que el meme: si no colaboras, algo (supongo que sera tu musica) va a desaparecer de la conciencia colectiva. Ademas, es uno de los primeros resultados, y todos los otros usan la frase en su sentido literal. No conozco a este grupo, [La Vela Puerca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Vela_Puerca), pero debe ser bastante famoso, pues tiene su propio pagina detallada de Wikipedia y la cancion es el primer resultado de una busqueda, en vez de los varios sitios de noticias que utilizaban la frase literalmente.

Muchos memes provienen de obras no muy famosas, asi que me puedo imaginar que la meme era una distorsion de esta cancion popular.